# visiting every node in linked list in java

Tags: java

```
String str = "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList";
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        LinkedList<String> linkedlist=new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.length-1; i++) {
              linkedlist.add(words[i]);           
        }
        ListIterator itr = linkedlist.listIterator();
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pstTemp = null;
              StringBuilder tokens = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                con = DBConnection.getJndiConnection();
                StringBuffer sbQry = new StringBuffer("SELECT  englishlex FROM   lex_hindi where   (domain='Tourism' or domain='Zgeneral') and englishlex=");

                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(itr.next());

                    tokens.append(itr.next());
                    sbQry.append("'"+tokens+ "',");
                    System.out.println(tokens.toString());


                }

                sbQry.append(" order by length(englishlex) desc");
                tokens.setLength(0);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(PhraseMarker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

---

I split the string on space basis. Now I want to visit every node of linklist and maintain current pointer and my aim is to check the phrase means "you can "whether it is present in database.

If yes then make it "you-can", if not then start searching for next token i.e  "use" onwards if "use either Iterator" is present then make it "use-either-Iterator" other wise "use either Iterator" remain as it is.

I have written a code but now how to proceed i am confuse?

Comment: Show us what you've tried (code you've written).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this correctly, but why don't you just loop throught your list...?

Comment: Please format your question. It is unreadable.

Comment: @m0skit0 i update my post and i add my code

Comment: @Cataclysm any problem in my post or code?

Comment: Can you please highlight on your program logic. Correct me if I am wrong. In a given string search for each String and if the data base entry found append "-" to the word or For the first loop take two words , and next take three words etc  or if consecutive words are in database put an "-"

Comment: @Kumar my table has some entries. My input sentence i given above.
i want to hyphanate the phrase which is present in my database that entry can be "You can" or "You can use either " or "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator" or "on Java ArrayList" then i want to make it hyphanated ex. "on-Java-ArrayList"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can suggest few things
   1) Token String Buffer is not required.
   2) After the loop create the statement object and get all the values.
   3) Now create a List from the result set
   4) Now send you Sentence Linked List and List from your database to another method which return resulted String 
   5) In the Method, create a StringBuffer
   5a) setBollean previousWordFound = false
   6) Iterate your Initial List for each word.
   7) Get each each word and check in another List (Which is from Result Set) use "Contains".
   8) If true in step 7 
         8a) previousWordFound found = true , append your String from 
      the Initial List with "-" else Nothing
         8b) previousWordFound = true
   9)  if false in step 7
          9a) previousWordFound = false

10) append the value to result string buffer

11) Finally return the result.

Here is the program, if result is not as per you expectation please let me know, I will update the my logic.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList";
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        LinkedList<String> linkedlist=new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= words.length-1; i++) {
            linkedlist.add(words[i]);
        }
        //Do your data base activitites

        //Assume your List as below
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("You");
        lst.add("use");
        lst.add("either");
        System.out.print(getPharsedValue(linkedlist, lst));
    }

    private static String getPharsedValue(LinkedList<String> linkedlWords, List<String> resultData){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        boolean previousWordFound = false;
        for(String word : linkedlWords){

            if (resultData != null && resultData.contains(word)){
                if(previousWordFound) {
                        word = "- " + word;
                }
                previousWordFound = true;
            } else {
                previousWordFound = false;
            }
            sb.append(word);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Result : You can use - either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList

Comment: I can give you final logic method, will that be ok

Comment: please any suggestions you have?

Comment: Thanks a lot we are little bit closer.but actually i want to fire one query which is not giving more resultset. Means i tried i start with "you can" whether this is present in table or not if yes then move forward check for next token whether entry for "you can use " is present if yes then again move forward check for "you can use either " if entry is present then again move forward if not then move back then hyphanate "you-can-use" then again start with "either" same process.so i want query which is give less resultset so that my performance is good.means process speed.

Comment: The most important thing i want is speed.processing time.
please give e some suggestion.

Comment: my database containing data like "you can" (coloum value) not "you" "can" like this means it contains phrase

Comment: How is your data in the table

Comment: data is in the phrase form like "ceo-national-commission-for-enterprises" and "Cephalothecium-roseum"

Comment: So you do have "-" in the data base as well.. Its new

Comment: Is this Urgent, I am in work at the moment. I can give you hint how to do that, if not I will do it tomorrow. Hint : Write a method which returns String[] and use this in your SQL query to reduce the data and number of hits.

Comment: Now What is String[], you need to create a method which has two parameters 1) StartsFrom int Variable (Which is start from which Phase) and other Parameter you Linked List.  final result like String[]{"you-can","you-can-use",... till the end}.       When you get the result set you get limited set lets take you got match till "you-can-use", take this append to String buffer. Now count number of Hypen it is 2 , so call the method again with 2+2(YOu got three words already used so start from next word) and your linked list.

Comment: You need to call your method startFrom is less than linkedList.size().